# How do I make the above tree list items auto close when I open the next item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree

Hope you are all doing well. Does anyone know how to close the tree item above or below when you open the next section? So the original section closes when you open the next section. (hope that makes sense).

Please see my code below and my codepen showing the code in action (http://cdpn.io/FDcBm)

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
ul {list-style-type: none}
ul li {margin-bottom: 0; padding-left: 1.5em}
.closed {background: url('http://www.planeswalkerslibrary.com/images/plus_icon.jpg') no-repeat 0 0; }

.open {background: url('http://www.planeswalkerslibrary.com/images/minus_icon.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;}

a {color:#0000FF;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#0000FF;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#0000FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */

</style>

</head>

<body>
<font face="verdana" size = 2>

<font size=3 color=#000080><b>Testing</b></font>
</br>

<hr>

</br>

Please choose the Test Item Below:

<ul>
<li><b>I have submitted a Test Car</b>

        <ul>
        <li>Error discovered in the same test

            <ul>
            <li>Underpayment
                <ul>
                <li><a href=test.html target="_blank">Error discovered before you test</a></li>
                </ul>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href=test.html target="_blank">Error discovered after Test</a> (e.g. you notice a test)</li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
            </li>   
            <ul>
            <li><a href=test.html target="_blank">Testing</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
        <li>Errors discovered in the test


            <ul>

            <li>Error discovered on or before the test
                <ul>
                <li>Underpayment
                <ul>
                <li><a href=test.html target="_blank">Error discovered before you test</a></li>
                </ul>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href=test.html target="_blank">Error discovered after you test<a/> (e.g. you notice an error in a test)</li>
                    </ul>

                    </li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=test.html target="_blank">Overtest</a></li>
                    </ul>   


        </ul>

            </li>
            <ul>

                <li><a href=test.html target="_blank">Error discovered on test</a></li>

            </ul>   
        </ul>

</li>

    </li>
    <li><b>I have submitted a test</b>
        <ul>
            <li><a href=test.html target="_blank">Incorrect date in test</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href=test.html target="_blank">Incorrect date in the same test</a> (NOTE: a test)</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href=test.html target="_blank">Incorrect test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><b><a href=test.html target="_blank">I have missed a test (and have submitted a test)</a></b></li>
    <li><b>I have submitted a test</b>
        <ul>
            <li>Wrong test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Wrong testy test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Wrong mega test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Wrong super test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Super test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Wrong mega super test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Wrong Date of test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Wrong Cat</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Wrong ultra test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Wrong master test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Wrong testy test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Wrong tester test</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('li').has('ul').click(function(event){
    if(this == event.target) 
        {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $(this).children('ul').toggle();
        }
    })
.addClass('closed')
.children('ul').hide();
});

</script>
</font>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With plugin: [collapse accordian](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse).

UDPATE:

Without plugin using the .siblings() method: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yT3H3/)

Just add these lines of code:

```
        if ($(this).siblings().hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).siblings().addClass('closed').removeClass('open').children('ul').hide();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Baba but id rather not use a plugin. Is there not a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Baba thats the idea though. I want it to do what that does.